# How to create single tile map for Universal(iPhone,iPad) for cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there any possibility to create a single tile map that can be used for iPhone(Normal&Retina) and iPad.

If Can't what is the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered this dilemma, and after a night of finding solutions, this is what I've found out.

You only need ONE .tmx file, and it should just be for the non-iphone resolution.

If you'd like to support all iOS devices,
you'd have something like this in your Xcode Project:

- TileMap.tmx
- TileAtlas.png
- TileAtlas-hd.png
- TileAtlas-ipadhd.png
- TileMap-ipad.png (optional) <- if you haven't set the ipad suffix to
  "-hd"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org). When building a universal app, it's a good idea to generate your (vector) art at the highest required resolution, and scale that same artwork down for every lower resolution device.